# About multiple modules(library with activities) in one application

Tags: android, module, dependencies

I have to make one app with big features. The features can grow depending on client. I want to have two different modules/projects for features, but single app/apk. I have a Dashboard module which has buttons that open number of other features(their activities). Is it really possible to have one app, and multiple modules like this?

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mg-DM5XAddk) as reference. I thought, maybe, from that video, common-module is application for me. buyer-project and seller-project can be libraries.

Then, I draw this diagram to ask the question.
[image: diagram]

So, in the diagram, I have a Dashboard Module. Dashboard Module has buttons that open other features (say musicPlayer, imageEditor, fileManager etc.). And, I, also, have one Common/Base module that is going to host base functionality required by all of modules and app itself.

So, in this case, Dashboard module is depended on Feature modules. And, Feature modules are depended on Common/Base module.

I thought Dashboard module will get access to Common/Base module through one of Feature modules, but it didn't work. I was unable to access a class in Common module from Dashboard module.

So, now, I have to add dependency of Common module into Dashboard module, right?

```
Dashboard -> Common
Dashboard -> Feature_1 -> Common
Dashboard -> Feature_2 -> Common
Dashboard -> Feature_3 -> Common
Dashboard -> Feature_4 -> Common
```

As you can see, Dashboard module needs Common module directly, do you think it will collide with Common module from Feature modules, **why or why not?**

**And,** in future if Feature modules have to access each other, it is going to be a bad design, right? With circular dependencies?

[image: circular_dependencies]

I don't know if this implementation is a good approach. How should I proceed with this? This is my first attempt at modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new Android application with "instantapp" enabled then Android will setup the following structure :

```
    base
     |
   feature
   /     \
 app   instantapp
```

Your case is handled by replacing `base` for `common` and treating `dashboard` as an additional feature.

```
           common
          /   |   \          ...\
   feature feature feature ...   dashboard
          \   |   /          .../
             app
```

Your `dashboard` should really be a simple view that references the summaries displayed upon it. These summaries should really be handled by the respective feature(s) since they will have access to the relevant model components and are best suited to provide the summaries for the dashboard. This should make it unnecessary for the `dashboard` to import the `common` module.

Two `feature`'s that are heavily co-dependent are either better off as a single feature, that is merge them together, or split up into three components comprising a common component and whatever is left of the original two features.

```
            common
            /    \          ...\
  sub.feature    feature ...   dashboard
   /       \        /          /
feature feature    /          /
      \     \     /       .../
       ------ app
```

If your `dashboard` module really needs to import the `common` module it should be fine to do so, most languages treat the case that a `common` import made by each `feature` does not clobber the same import made later by say the `dashboard`. If the language does not support this then you have to look into isolating it by use of `private`/`public` declarations.